# How to add JSON objects to an array in another JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a `JSON` file as :

`var info = [{
    "place": "Turkey",
    "username": "jhon"
}, {
    "place": "Dubai",
    "username": "bruce"
}, {
    "place": "Italy",
    "username": "Wayne"
}];`

I have an `HTML` form as :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

<form onsubmit="addToJSON();">
First name:<br>
<input type="text" id="place">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" id="username">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
<script src="data.json"></script>
<script>
function addToJSON(){
    alert("inside JS");
    var x = document.getElementById('place').value;
    var y = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var obj = {
    place: x,
    username: y
};
localStorage.setItem("info",JSON.stringify(obj));
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get the values that the user inputs in the form and add them to the `JSON` var that I have. But I am going wrong somewhere.Help much appreciated! So that if the user enters `wayne` and `india` in the form, my `JSON` array must have those two objects added to them. Plus they should reflect in the file.

Comment: info is  a global variable in another file?

Comment: yes! it is a global variable @raghavendra

Comment: then directly add obj to info array

Comment: how do I do the same? @raghavendra

Comment: use info.push(obj ); after obj in your code

Comment: at last, you can get json from JSON.stringify(info)

Comment: will that allow the changes to be reflected in the JSON file when I view it? @raghavendra

Comment: it won't reflect in file it will reflect in info array

Comment: is there any way I could make the changed reflect in the file as well? @raghavendra

Comment: that array you have to send it back to server and write it or use cookies or webstoreage

Comment: how do I get it on client side?@raghavendra

Comment: *I have a JSON file* — That's JavaScript, not JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to write to arbitrary files or URLs from browser-side JavaScript.

You would need to bundle the data up in an HTTP request (using `XMLHttpRequest` or just getting rid of the JavaScript and submitting the form normally), send it to an HTTP server, and then have a server side program (written in the programming language of your choice, which could be JavaScript via Node.JS) edit the file.

(Editing files on servers is generally a bad idea and using a database is normally a better option).

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

<form onsubmit="addToJSON();">
First name:<br>
<input type="text" id="place">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" id="username">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
<script src="data.json"></script>
<script>
if(!localStorage.getItem('info'))
    localStorage.setItem("info",JSON.stringify(info));
else
    info = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("info"));
function addToJSON(){
    alert("inside JS");
    var x = document.getElementById('place').value;
    var y = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var obj = {
    place: x,
    username: y
    };
    info.push(obj);
    localStorage.setItem("info",JSON.stringify(info));
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried what you gave but the changes still aren't reflecting in my JSON file! @raghavendra

Comment: see the console it is reflecting in info item

Comment: the alert I have inside the JavaScript did not pop up as well, so it isnt going within the JS also. @raghavendra

Comment: above answer is true. but you can get info object which is stored in the web browser.

Comment: try the http://jsfiddle.net/vdazU/1234/ add two three names and refresh the pages. see the console